# Problems accessing properties in a mapped type of generics

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

For better or worse, I have an API that streams data in a 3-tuple: `(EntityName, FieldName, Value)`. An `id` is also provided, but it's probably moot for the sake of this conversation.

`EntityName` represents a record type and `FieldName` should be a key of that particular record. `Value` should be an appropriate value for the type of `FieldName`.

I'm trying to figure out how I can write a function, given this tuple, can validate the `Value` if I know that `EntityName` and `FieldName` are already valid.

I've tried to write this code in several ways and the one I'm presenting below, I believe, is the most elegant. But, I have not been able to find anything that works without making type assertions and I'm curious as to why the type checker can't figure out that this will work, given the way `Validator` is defined and the way `isValueValid` is defined, I would expect no complaints.

With that said, I'm not so advanced as to know whether I'm hitting a theoretical limit on type checking or if this might be a bug?

```
export enum EntityName {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
};

interface IEntityA {
  fieldA: boolean;
}

interface IEntityB {
  fieldB: string;
}

type Entity<Name extends EntityName> =
  Name extends EntityName.A ? IEntityA :
  Name extends EntityName.B ? IEntityB :
    never;

const Validator: {
  [Name in EntityName]: {
    [FieldName in keyof Entity<Name>]: (value: unknown) => value is Entity<Name>[FieldName];
  };
} = {
  [EntityName.A]: {
    fieldA: (value: unknown): value is boolean => typeof value === 'boolean',
  },
  [EntityName.B]: {
    fieldB: (value: unknown): value is string => typeof value === 'string',
  },
};

const isValueValid = <
  Name extends EntityName,
  FieldName extends keyof Entity<Name>,
>(
  entityName: Name,
  fieldName: FieldName,
  value: unknown,
): value is Entity<Name>[FieldName] => {
  return Validator[entityName][fieldName](value);
};
```

The compiler gives me this error inside of `isValueValid`:

```
Type 'FieldName' cannot be used to index type '{ A: { fieldA: (value: unknown) => value is boolean; }; B: { fieldB: (value: unknown) => value is string; }; }[Name]'.
```

Interestingly, the parameters passed to `isValueValid` are type checked properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to instantiate a variable of type `FieldName` inside the body of `isValueValid` I got an error, meaning as a Generic, `FieldName` could be a subtype of `keyof Entity<Name>` making some values invalid for either `IEntityA` or `IEntityB` like `string | number | symbol`, so that's slightly insecure. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29049

And after trying to limit the type of `FieldName` to `keyof Entity<EntityName.A>` for simplicity I found that everything works out, but `keyof Entity<Name>` seems to delay the type resolution to a point where is not possible to know if `FieldName` is either `IEntityA | IEntityB | never` according to TypeScript Designer this is a design limitation for conditional types. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29225#issuecomment-451678927

So this is also related, looks like that condition is referred as "stuck" type https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29413#issuecomment-455390404